# At boot, howto start systemd service described in a NFS path

Tags: boot, services, systemd, nfs, centos-8

on our centos 8 servers, we have many custom services to start at boot time.
To split things between system and "our stuff", we put everything in our path `/truc`

Thoses services are `enabled` via a kind of `systemctl enable /truc/etc/systemd/machin.service`

After a `daemon-reload` that's ok.  In my production context, job is done.

But on dev / QA contexts, `/truc` is a remote NFS mounting on a file server.

At boot time, /truc doesn't contain services files, so none of them starts

I tried things with `After=remote-fs.target` or `RequiresMountsFor=/truc` but, anyway, file is not read has it is not yet present while booting

Any tips / hack ?!

Has this happens on a dev server, I can add a "hack.service" somewhere in the system path. But I cannot move/copy service files outside this NFS mount

thanks

Comment: I guess you'll have to mess with the initramfs so that it makes sure `/truc` (in the real root sense) is mounted before "switching root". (Some people like to have seperate `/usr` partition. I guess you can try to find out how is that normally "handled" in the distro you use and see if the approach can apply to your case as well.)

Comment: `But I cannot move/copy service files outside this NFS mount` Btw I don't get this. Wouldn't you really be touching files (well, I mean, making symlinks) somewhere outside this mount anyway, when you have the services inside enabled?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to manually create a systemd service for my minecraft server instance. There is an option on the service config file (mine was at /etc/systemd/system/mcservice.service) which you can define a delay for it to start. Assuming the service runs as root, you just have to add to the **[Service]** section the following line (fill in your path):

```
ExecStartPre=mount -t nfs <IP source>:<remote path> <local path>
```

After saving the file, you can live test the service by reloading systemctl using:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

If the service user is not root, or the mounting of the NFS mountpoint is done by other service (which runs as root), you just have to replace the mount command on **ExecStartPre** by a simple 'sleep 10', for example (adjust time accordingly). Also, you can use the option **After** and pointing to your NFS mounting service (it will run after it has finished mounting).

Good luck, I hope I have helped.

Comment: The problem in the OPs case isn't really about "holding back" a service start. Rather it's about the fact that systemd does NOT load a service file *just before* trying to start it, but more or less, before it tries to start anything. Basically it loads all the (valid) files from the predefined paths and order them, then start them according to the order. And the problem here is that some service files are not there when systemd does this "first step".

Comment: Btw, even in *your* case, I think the proper way is to have a mount unit written and rely on dependencies (if you really want to have this kind of "custom automount", I mean; otherwise, probably `RequiresMountsFor=` as the OP has written)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by remarks and comments, as this is for dev/QA servers, I tried to get a "quick & dirty" solution.

in root's crontab, this seems to do the job :

```
@reboot sleep 30 && /sbin/ldconfig && /bin/systemctl daemon-reload && /bin/systemctl restart machin.service
```

My first attempt was not good because of `ldconfig` instead of `/sbin/ldconfig`